# I can't understand this shape from the python code

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm new to python. I'm searching on google about python code to get street sign detection, I found some code but I can't understand what the code means.

```
elif dominant_color[0] > 80:
            zone_0 = square[square.shape[0]*3//8:square.shape[0]
                            * 5//8, square.shape[1]*1//8:square.shape[1]*3//8]
            cv2.imshow('Zone0', zone_0)
            zone_0_color = warnadominan(zone_0, 1)

            zone_1 = square[square.shape[0]*1//8:square.shape[0]
                            * 3//8, square.shape[1]*3//8:square.shape[1]*5//8]
            cv2.imshow('Zone1', zone_1)
            zone_1_color = warnadominan(zone_1, 1)

            zone_2 = square[square.shape[0]*3//8:square.shape[0]
                            * 5//8, square.shape[1]*5//8:square.shape[1]*7//8]
            cv2.imshow('Zone2', zone_2)
            zone_2_color = warnadominan(zone_2, 1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: square. shape is a tuple, dimensions of the array.

Comment: The code would be clearer if it assigned the two elements of the shape to variable, e.g. `h, w = square.shape`, and then used indexing expressions like `square[h*3//8:h*5//8, w*1//8:w*3//8]`, which is selecting a middle half of the rows, and a quarter of the columns (roughly).

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming square has shape (8, 8)
```

I think this diagram might help:

[image]

Edit: The code is trying to extract the zones shown in the image